# Adding authentication functionality to soap server (Using Zend)?

Tags: zend-framework, soap

I have a soap server that is created like so:

```
class ServerController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function serverAction()
    {
       memcache_flush();
       Zend_Registry::get('cache')->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);

       $server = new SoapServer("http://####/services/soap-server/wsdl");
       $server->setClass('SOAP_Server_Map');
       $server->handle();
    }
}
```

I want to add authentication to it so that whenever anyone makes a call to a function in "`SOAP_Server_Map`", it checks that the credentials supplied in the SoapClient options array('login' and 'password') are valid.

Does anyone have any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 6):

To add authentication to either Zend_Soap_Server or Zend_Json_Server, simply specify the HTTP authentication in either your HTTP server (ie: Apache) config or .htaccess file. The following .htaccess file should work:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Supreme Data Services"
AuthUserFile /var/www/localhost/passwd
Require valid-user
```

Make sure you keep your password file out of the docroot for security purposes. The password file can be made by using htpasswd that comes with Apache. Naturally, you can use more advanced authentication types.

In order to make use of the service(s), you must now specify a username and password when making a request. If you are using Zend Framework to create your client, you can do the following for SOAP:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

And the following for JSONRPC:

```
$http = new Zend_Http_Client();
$http->setAuth($username, $password);
$client = new Zend_Json_Client($uri, $http);
```

Comment: Surely this only provides a very basic level of protection.  Do you think SSL or ws-security are worth looking into?

Comment: As suggested in my answer "Naturally, you can use more advanced authentication types". Authentication and encryption may be related. However they are not the same thing. What would you like to protect? Access or the data itself? You should probably at least use AuthType Digest. If the data is sensitive, then of course add encryption (SSL). Bear in mind the client needs to support the authentication and encryption mechanisms. Unfortunately, some SOAP clients only support Basic authentication. :/

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem and I have the following thoughts:

I do not know if SOAP is/should be state-full or stateless, can we open a session and if the user has supplied some form of credential keep her logged in for some period of time?

The other way I am thinking of solving this is through API-keys, say for example giving a key: ABCDKEY and having the url as:

http://####/services/soap-server/ABCDKEY

This introduces security risks (the magic link attack), but I've seen it implemented in RSS personalized feeds etc.
Any comments?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? HTTP authentication is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://pt.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#101503